# Nuxt Bulma app can't access SCSS variables

Tags: vue.js, sass, nuxt.js, bulma

I've created a `Nuxt` app with Bulma included and would like to access/override the Bulma variables in my `.vue` files. I've followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/tetreault/nuxt-bulma-sass) which seem to match what I found in several other locations but I'm still getting an error when trying to access the `$primary` variable in my `.vue` file.

Here's my `assets/css/main.scss` file:

```
@import "~bulma/sass/utilities/_all.sass";
@import "~bulma/bulma";
```

My `nuxt.config.js` modules section:

```
modules: [
    ['nuxt-sass-resources-loader', './assets/css/main.scss']
],
```

And my `.vue` file:

```html
<template>
    <section class="container">
        <div class="my-title">
            About
        </div>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.my-title {
    color: $primary;
}
</style>
```

Here's the error message in the terminal:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):                                                                                                                                                                                                                       friendly-errors 11:51:52

    color: $primary;
          ^
      Undefined variable: "$primary".
      in /Data/dev/GIT/Homepage/source/pages/about/index.vue (line 16, column 12)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           friendly-errors 11:51:52
 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--9-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--9-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--9-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./pages/about/index.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss& 4:14-384 14:3-18:5 15:22-392
 @ ./pages/about/index.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&
 @ ./pages/about/index.vue
 @ ./.nuxt/router.js
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi eventsource-polyfill webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true&timeout=30000&ansiColors=&overlayStyles=&name=client&path=/__webpack_hmr/client ./.nuxt/client.js
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** I've narrowed it down to the `nuxt.config.js` modules setup by importing the `.scss` directly in the `.vue` file. This works which tell me the imports in the `main.scss` the file is working fine.

Comment: have you defined $primary in main.scss?

Comment: @Andrew1325 $primary is one of the variables defined by Bulma so I shouldn't need to define it. I actually did try defining it too with no change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I wasn't able to get it working with nuxt-sass-resources-loader but I did get it working with style-resources-module from here https://github.com/nuxt-community/style-resources-module. Once I installed style-resources-module, I just added it to my nuxt.config.js modules section and added the appropriate styleResources section as follows:

```
modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/style-resources'
],

styleResources: {
    scss: [
        './assets/css/main.scss'
    ]
},
```

Comment: this only imports the common variables declared inside _initial-variables.scss in bulma, what about the variables defined inside each component?

Answer (score 2):

This config options provides to load any scss/sass file that specified by you before other files via webpack. You can interfere webpack config via [these options](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#loaders) that provide by nuxt. To experience more sass loader configuration you can check [webpack sass loader section](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/).

> Don't forget install node-sass and sass-loader to use sass/scss file
>   in your app as mentioned by [nuxt documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-css#the-css-property).

```
// nuxt.config.js

build: {
  loaders: {
    sass: {
        prependData: "@import '~bulma/sass/utilities/_all.sass;",
      }
    }
  }
```